# How may I find the pattern of a table.

Tags: functions, computational-complexity

I have the following table:

```
Processes | Failures:
12            5
15            6
18            7
19            8
21            9
24            10
27            11
28            12
30            13
33            14
36            15
37            16
39            17
```

and I want to know how many processes I need to endure 1 failure in average.

Which should become something between 2f+1 and 3f+1 processes for f failures.

I also have this table:

```
Pr. Msg
12  28
15  40
18  54
19  70
21  88
24  108
25  130
27  154
```

Which should describe how many messages we need to send for n processes
(message complexity) - which should be somewhere between O(n) and O(n^2)
But I wasn't able to find a single "simple" formula describing these rows.

Comment: In the first table, the pattern in the differences seem to be +3, +3, +1, +2.

Comment: It is. But how do I get it into the correct desired form?

Comment: I doubt there's a convenient simple formula unless you can make it piecewise or use regressions... I can think of a really crazy way to fit the data that requires sign function, but I sincerely doubt that's the intended solution.

Comment: I found some crazy forms. But, I unfortunately need it in the form "xf+c".
I don't need an exact form but something +- would be helpful already.